# Como personalizar os ícones do material stepper?

Tags: angular, front-end, angular-material

Boa tarde. Estou tentando modificar os ícones que vem por padrão no stepper do material design mas não consigo encontrar nenhuma solução viável.
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Este ícone de editar que me refiro. Há alguma forma de colocar um ícone customizado?

Uma outra duvida, é possível identificar qual step está com erro de validação no formulário? Ou ativo?

Agradeço.

Comment: Também preciso disso, encontrou como?

Comment: Não encontrei solução. Tive que trabalhar com a troca em tempo de execução mesmo, capturando os elementos no DOM e manipulando.

Comment: Imaginei, tentei fazer assim também e acabei desistindo, vlw pela resposta, vou tentar novamente. Abs